# Brewery API won't connect, what am I doing wrong? (Noob)

Tags: javascript, api

I'm having a little trouble connecting to this brewery API (https://www.openbrewerydb.org/documentation/01-listbreweries).  I'm working on a webpage that allows users to input a city they're traveling to and spit out the breweries within that city. I'm not too familiar with API's, and don't know what code needs to be changed so it can be listed on my page. Could anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong? I know this is probably a simple fix, but I am a little lost right now.

```
const breweryName = document.querySelector(".brewery-name");
function getBrewery(name) {
console.log(data.name);
lat = lat.toString();
lon = lon.toString();
fetch(
 'https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries?by_city=princeton')    
 
 .then((response) => {
   response.json().then((data) => {
     const brewery = data.brewery;
     console.log(brewery);

     if (brewery.length === 0) {
       const breweryWarning = document.createElement("h3");
       breweryWarning.textContent = "Sorry, no breweries in that city!";
       breweryList.appendChild(brewerytWarning);
       return;
     }
     brewery.forEach((e) => {
       // creating date object and converting it to readable format
       let date = luxon.DateTime.fromISO(e.datetime_local).toLocaleString(
         luxon.DateTime.DATETIME_MED
       );
       const breweryItem = document.createElement("li");
       const breweryLink = document.createElement("a");
       const breweryImage = document.createElement("img");
       breweryLink.setAttribute("href", e.url);
       breweryImage.setAttribute("src", e.performers[0].images.huge);
       breweryLink.setAttribute("class", "event-block");
       breweryItem.textContent = `${e.title}- ${date}`;
       breweryLink.appendChild(breweryItem);
       breweryLink.appendChild(breweryImage);
       breweryList.appendChild(breweryLink);
     });
   });
 })
 .catch((err) => {
   console.log(err.message);
 });
}
```

Comment: Have you used your dev tools (F12) to debug the code and see if there are errors?

Comment: I have been using to figure it out but it doesn't display on the console.  So there must be a connection error

Comment: Have a look at both the console tab, and the network tab, and see what they say.

Comment: Where, for example have you defined, `breweryList`?

Answer (score 1):

It's important for you to understand [what information the API returns](https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries?by_city=princeton). There are no properties for performances, or images, and it's `website_url` not `url`.

I added in a `breweryList` element, and I hope this working code helps you out a little bit.

```js
const breweryList = document.querySelector(".brewerylist");

function getBrewery(name) {

  const endpoint = `https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries?by_city=${name}`;

  fetch(endpoint)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {;

      if (!data.length) {

        const breweryWarning = document.createElement('h3');
        breweryWarning.textContent = 'Sorry, no breweries in that city!';
        breweryList.appendChild(breweryWarning);

      } else {

        data.forEach(el => {

          const breweryItem = document.createElement('li');
          const breweryLink = document.createElement('a');
          // const breweryImage = document.createElement('img');
          breweryLink.setAttribute('href', el.website_url);
          // breweryImage.setAttribute('src', el.performers[0].images.huge);
          breweryLink.setAttribute('class', 'event-block');
          breweryItem.textContent = el.name;
          breweryLink.appendChild(breweryItem);
          // breweryLink.appendChild(breweryImage);
          breweryList.appendChild(breweryLink);

        });

      }

    });

}

getBrewery('princeton');
```

```html
<ul class="brewerylist"></ul>
```